# Struts2 message resource bundle folder hierarchy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, struts2

I'm trying to create a "double folder/package" hierarchy in Eclipse to split my actual Java code from the message resource bundles that the Struts2 framework uses. To do that I created two source folders in Eclipse, one called src and one called resources. For Struts2 to properly match the correct action class to the right resource bundle, the hierarchy must match.

In the image below something similar is done except folders are used instead of packages and the actual split up is one level deeper.

[image]

However, Eclipse won't let met create packages with **the same name** in the resources folder aswell as in the src folder. (If I try, i just get an empty package "com" in my resources folder?)

So I'm forced to put the message resource bundles a t the same place as my actual classes, like in the picture below. This can get ugly quickly If I need more languages or create more packages.

How can I neatly organize and separate this?

[image]

Comment: Sounds more like you're doing something wrong; if your files are being packaged correctly, the package hierarchy is what is used. This is handled automatically by Maven; if you're using some other mechanism you'll need to provide details. If both `java` and `resources` are listed as source folders this works in Eclipse as well.

Comment: The `resources` folder isn't source folder it is resource folder. Not kidding.

Comment: I'm not using Maven. After looking at several projects, I noticed the main/java main/reources/ main/tests folder structure seems to be something maven specific. I thought it could be accomplished in eclipse without having Maven